# For loop to calc desc stats for each distinct value in a subcategory column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to calculate the descriptive statistics of the 'Variance' column for each distinct value in the Subcategory column of my dataset. Rather than do it manually, I'd like to use a for loop. I'm getting a value error, but not sure what I might be missing. Thank you!

```
subcategories = ['abc', 'cab', 'bac', 'cde', 'edc', 'fgh', 'ghb']

for i in subcategories:
    if df[df.Subcategory == i]:
        print(df['Variance'].describe())
```

When I run my code, I get the following Value Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.Subcategory == i` returns a boolean series. The if condition doesn't know how to return on a series. You need this:

```
for i in subcategories:
    print(df.loc[df.Subcategory == i, 'Variance'].describe())
```